# How to use multiple language in Zend Framework using multiple language files in language folder

Tags: zend-framework, zend-translate

I want to convert my system in multiple languages which is build in zend framework. I have a language folder and this folder I created multiple language foldrs like en,jp,ch etc. All language folders have their own language files like en.php,jp.php,ch.php and have constants defined in them. So How can i use this language system in Zend Framework.

Comment: Are the [Zend_Translate docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.html) insufficient in some way? What have you tried that has not worked?

Comment: If the documentation isn't working for you, providing us with your current code which you are attempting to use may be of use for us to further help you out.